# Android , push FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I need help about fcm push problem in android.
When I receive the push on the phone , I cant receive it on the log that i put ine the FirebaseMessagingService.

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "FROM:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e(TAG, "FROM:");

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        //Check if the message contains data
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        //Check if the message contains notification

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Mesage body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Could you also post a sample of the payload you're sending?